# vs 2012 generate web service reference with minOccurs="0"

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I am working with third party consuming a web service running on an Apache server. There are fields with option minOccurs="0". I used 'add service reference...' command to load the wsdl file. In the final cs file fields with minOccurs="0" are not marked optional. They are treated as regular class member. I then will get error message when I desearilize data returned back without these optional fields. How do I fix this problem?

```
 <complexType name="contactType">
      <sequence>
         <element minOccurs="0" name="refid" type="ingType32"/>
         <element minOccurs="0" name="title" type="csccom:StringType32"/>
         <element name="firstname" type="csccom:StringType32"/>
      </sequence>
</complexType>

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:csca:xml:ns:csccom-1.1")]
public partial class contactType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string refidField;

    private string titleField;

    private string firstnameField;

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="token", Order=0)]
    public string refid {
        get {
            return this.refidField;
        }
        set {
            this.refidField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("refid");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="token", Order=1)]
    public string title {
        get {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set {
            this.titleField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("title");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="token", Order=2)]
    public string firstname {
        get {
            return this.firstnameField;
        }
        set {
            this.firstnameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("firstname");
        }
    }
}
```

> stack trace
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the WSDL and show the relevant generated code.

Comment: Exactly what problem do you have if those elements are missing?

Comment: Error occurred during deserialization process.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the raw return data I noticed that there is a data field with nil="true". .NET didn't generate the right code file for this field. The class always expect a datetime value for this field. The service works well after changed the field definition to Nullable. It's not a ideal solution and have to manually do it every time updating service.